# Extracting Data from an Id tag (ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, mailto

I am still learning and been re-searching the topic for couple of hours.

The following code in my views displays the email address in the forum

```
<form id="user_details" action="<%= request.path %>" method="post" >
<output id="email">
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is make the email text a hyperlink (just like mailto). I just have no idea what the right syntax for this would be.

Thank you so much!

Comment: how does the email get there? This is not a rails form but a plain old HTML form. Is there a script putting it there? If rails would put it there should be an erb tag (`<%=`) involved.

Comment: Thank you! so now I know it in old html....it is not rails putting it there, but it should be right? I find this bit of code in user controller, you think it has anything to do with this?

def modify

    puts "Modifying user"

    CONN.basic_auth cookies[:login],''

    # These should be posted as form elements
    email = params[:email]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read up a bit on the output tag and it is supposed to be the result of a script calculation. It doesn't really fit in with what you are doing here. The output tag is not a form tag so your form won't post the email address in the output tag. However - you are asking for how to show it as a mailto link. You can replace the output tag with an anchor tag instead:

```
<a href="" id="email"></a>
```

then you have to find the script that populates the field with the id `email` and see to that it also populates the href attribute with `mailto:email@example.com`. If this is jquery it would be something like:

```
var updateEmailTag = function(email) {
    $('#email').html(email);
    $('#email').attr('href', 'mailto:' + email );
}
```

If you instead want to do this on the server side you'll have to find where the email comes from and then use the mail_to helper as suggested by Aditya Kapoor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Rails helper, mail_to out there that is designed to do exactly this...

Read more from here.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to

Comment: I read the whole page, it didn't help. Because there 1000's of users I need to know the users email when writing mail_to... I don't know the syntax of using it when my email changes for every user.

Comment: srry i didn't understood ur last comment

Comment: <output id="email">  shows the current's user email. How do I incorporate this into the mail_to?

Comment: <output id="email"><%= mail_to current_user.email %></output>

Comment: Almost, there is no "current user". This is somebody else's code so still trying to figure it out.

Comment: It is also overwriting the mail_to.. so you can't see the mail_to link as the output takes over

Comment: No it did not... :( "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<#<Class:0x000001018c1200>:0x00000101e43020>"

Comment: current_user is the helper function which you need to define that would find the existing user that is present in the system....In you case if you just want the emails then you can simply substitute the value of email instead of current_user.email.

Comment: As you would progress you will read more about the current_user being used extensively in the apps..

Comment: @AdityaKapoor: what if it's not current user, but some another user? :)

Comment: do you have actually a User model? Where you get emails from?

Comment: I am so bad at this. Spent5 hours last night trying to learn it. I don't know if I have a user model. There is a user helper file and a user controller but I can not see how those correlate to <output id"email">  same works for name, so <output id="first> would give me the first name. so i tried doing <a href="mailto:<output id="email">> email </a>   but that doesn't work and i don't know the right syntax.